# Why the [^A] does not work?

Tags: regex

Why the regular expression:

```
changes\s*=\s*[^A].*
```

matches

```
changes =  AssignDictionary(out
```

What I want to find is no words starting with character "A" (`[^A]`) following the spaces (`\s*`), and it supposes not to match that line...what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `'  '` (the two spaces) match `\s*[^A]` (any amount of space followed by something not A, a space is not A).

Comment: (and even if there only was one space, it would still match...)

Comment: Said on the other view: it will only avoid `=A` with no space between = and A

Answer (score 4):

The `[^A]` does not work because of backtracking. `\s*` matches zero or more whitespaces, and then the engine backtracks to accommodate for a `non-A`. Since there are two spaces after `=`, the second space is matched with `[^A]` -> there is a match.

See Step 12 & 13 ([regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tT6vC9/1)):

[image]

If you want to fail the match when there is an `A` after `=`, you need a *negative lookahead*:

```
changes\s*=(?!\s*A)\s*.*
           ^^^^^^^^
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/tT6vC9/2)

Or another PCRE variation: [`changes\s*=\s*+(?!A).*`](https://regex101.com/r/tT6vC9/3) (check if the character is not `A` after all whitespaces after `=`).

If your regex engine supports atomic groups or possessive quantifiers, you can **make your regex work** by preventing backtracking into the `\s*` construct:

```
changes\s*=\s*+[^A].*
             ^^ (possessive quantifier)

changes\s*=(?>\s*)[^A]\s*.*
           ^^    ^ - atomic group
```

And in case your engine does not support atomic groups, nor possessive quantifiers, you can disable backtracking with a capture group/backreference combination (to emulate an atomic group):

```
changes\s*=(?=(\s*))\1[^A].*
```

See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/tT6vC9/4).

Still, the first solution with a lookahead is preferable since it seems the most universal one. The fastest looks to be the one with the possessive quantifier.

Comment: I suppose working a `\b` in there might also solve the problem.

Comment: Hm, no idea if `\b` should work, but I have just checked and the original regex will work if we prevent backtracking with an atomic group or a possessive quantifier.

Comment: For the record, `\s*\b[^A]` does seem to work, and is IMO a lot simpler.

Comment: @deceze: What if there is `:`, not a word character?

Comment: We'd need to know the file format specification for that. If that's a possibility, then yes, it's no good.

Comment: `\s*+(?!A)\s*.*` => `\s*+(?!A).*`

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to get that with plain regex. Just indicate what is not a valid character following the arbitrary number of spaces before the "not A". As you indicated this is: not A, but of course also "not a space". 
Otherwise backtracking would allow a space preceeding an A in tat position to 
be matched for the "not-A" and defeat your intentions.

Using **changes\s*=\s*[^A\s].*** will match anything that does not have an A or a white space after the spaces following the equals sign (and extend the match to end-of-line/end-of-input.